# Reproduce statsmodel calculation

Tags: python, matplotlib, regression, statsmodels

I am running an OLS regression with statsmodel, using clustered standard errors (https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.get_robustcov_results.html):

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

model = smf.ols(model_string, data=df1).fit(cov_type = 'cluster', cov_kwds={'groups': df1['correctedSE']})
```

I run a loop with different specifications and would like to visualise the the coefficients of all iterations.

I extract the coefficient and standard error in every iteration with:

```
coe = model.params["variable_of_interest"] 
se = model.bse["variable_of_interest"]
List_coefficients.append(coe)
List_standard_errors.append(se)
```

I create a simple dataframe out of the lists then want to visualise the coefficients in an errorbar from matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.errorbar(df["loop_rounds"], df["Coefficient"], yerr=df150["Standard_e"])
```

However, when doing so, the confidence intervals are somehow calculated different and some coefficients in the graph are currently significant.

What would be the best way to correct for the calculation difference (e.g. extract different parameters from statsmodel, manually adjust standard errors, change in errorbar)? 
If manually editing is the solution, where can I find the formula for the clustered standard errors?

Thank you

Comment: Hard to trace without complete example, but what are dimensions of `coe`?

Comment: sorry, but it would be a lot of code and I am more interested in the approach. coe is a float variable, same a se.

Comment: Your prose covers the appoach, and it dounds reasonable, but does not reveal the error,  consider injecting some values to a question. Eg hard to judge what is inside df and df150. Probably working on a minimal example can reveal an error that you have.

Comment: The problem is that I would need to simulate heteroskedastic errors, which is not very easy.